# Encrypt and Decrypt password on different computers

Tags: bash, openssl

Currently I am writing a little script which stores an encrypted password in a config file and decrypt it when it needs to use the password. I know that this is not the safest way and it should only make it "unreadable" for people. I have encrypted my password with:

```
echo PasswordToEncrypt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:PasswordForEncryptAndDecrypt
```

Now I got my encrypted password and tried to decrypt it and it works fine. But after I tried to decrypt the password on a different computer, it can't decrypt it anymore. Also if I encrypt the password again it looks different than the encrypted password on the first computer.

My question is: Is there any method to encrypt and decrypt a password with openssl with the same result on different computers? So that I can encrypt a password in Comouter A and decrypt it in Computer B?

Comment: "Also if I encrypt the password again it looks different than the encrypted password on the first computer." That's normal. Even if you do the encryption twice on the same computer, the result will be different. It's not related to the problem you're having.

Comment: Is your working theory that OpenSSL can only decrypt data that was encrypted on the same machine? This is not the case. It's undoubtedly a bug your scripts. The fact that it works on a single machine is not a guarantee that the script is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt a file and decrypt it on another computer, the decrypted data will be the same. Encryption becomes useless otherwise. I think you see different output because you forgot to give the `-md` option.

To encrypt:

```
$ echo TEST | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -salt -pass pass:my_password > enc.bin
```

And decrypt:

```
$ cat enc.bin | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc  -md md5 -pass pass:my_password
TEST
```

Just to give you the option to use keys:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out key.priv 4096
$ openssl rsa -in key.priv -pubout -out key.pub
$ echo TEST | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -pass file:key.pub > tmp.bin
$ cat tmp.bin | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -pass file:key.pub > tmp.txt
TEST
```

Comment: Can it be a problem the I encrypted it on the latest Ubuntu version and try to decrypt it on an older raspberry pi 2 with raspian? I somewhere read that a different OpenSSL version could cause issues?

Comment: That's most likely the problem. The `-md` option, for example, is changed from `md5` to `sha256`. In recent versions of OpenSSL (1.1.1) wants you to add `-iter 1000 -pbkdf2`, which will not work for 1.1.0. Did the solution work for you?

Comment: With the `-md` option you set the message digest. If you're encrypting without `-md` option, it currently defaults to `sha256`. In older versions it defaults to `md5`. They are different incompatible hash functions and result in a `bad decrypt` error.